# PHP mysql query not producing result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with the below query not producing a result.  There is nothing wrong with the query.  But it is being run after a lot of other time and memory consuming instructions within a PHP script.  If I restrict the number of operations performed in the script before this query is executed, it works.

How do I find out what the problem is?  Is there a way to be notified if the script exceeds memory or execution time limitations?  Or could there be another reason?

```
$query="SELECT * FROM user" or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query($query);

if($result)
{
    success();
}
else //error
{
    failure();
}
```

Comment: As you said the problem lies in the resource hungry codes preceding it. The issue can be accurately tackled only after seeing those sections of the code.

Answer (score 2):

`or die(mysql_error())` should be added after the query is executed:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM user";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, the else will never execute because you `die()` before that.

I suggest this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM user";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if($result)
{
    success($result);
}
else //error
{
    failure(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `or` with string.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM user";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if($result)
{
    success();
}
else //error
{
    failure();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can always check if there is a mysql error by using `mysql_error()` which returns the mysql error string if it exists.

Second, to see if your query returned any rows, use `mysql_num_rows($result) > 0`.